# python char replace while readingfile

Tags: python, numpy

I have a text/csv file with following composition. it's 8 million records or more

```
1, 10721, 12478, 5, 0, 0, 0,"A1","0555"
1, 10722, 12479, 1, 0, 0, 0,"A2","1555"
```

where first 7 columns are integers and then 7th and 8th column is quoted with " char. I want to read the 8th column as integer since it's time of the day.

My Question: How I can remove this " char and use this column as integer instead of string while keeping the computing/ram to minimal.

Also currently I am using numpy.genfromtxt. I noticed that dtype is an option but it if I give integer to last column it just converts it to -1 instead of integer.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If it's the time of day, wouldn't you be better off reading it as two ints (hour and minute) which then you can get a nice `datetime.time` object from? (just asking)

Comment: @BorrajaX yes this could be an option. But I am still not sure how you will read that while still using genfromtxt?

Comment: Oh... well... I missed that part (I was going towards how to read a csv file with the regular csv module).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that comes to mind (and please, use carefully, since I know **almost nothing** about NumPy) would be creating your own *converter* for the 8th column (the first is zero):

Let's say you put your data in a file... eeeermmm... called `stack_063.csv`. You could do this:

```
data = numpy.genfromtxt("stack_063.csv", dtype=int, delimiter=',',
                        converters={
                            8: lambda x: float(x.replace('"', '')) / 100
                        })
print(data)
```

That way, you'd get a list like the following:

```
[(1, 10721, 12478, 5, 0, 0, 0, -1, 5.55)
 (1, 10722, 12479, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 15.55)]
```

If you want an int, just have your converter be: `lambda x: int(x.replace('"', ''))`

**EDIT**:

Playing a little more with NumPY, I've seen that there's another thing that you could do, maybe. That is declaring your data type for the 8th column as a `numpy.object` and then get an actual `datetime.time` from it:

```
import numpy
import datetime

data_types = [
    numpy.uint16,
    numpy.int_,
    numpy.int_,
    numpy.int_,
    numpy.int_,
    numpy.int_,
    numpy.int_,
    numpy.dtype((str, 35)),
    numpy.object_
]
data = numpy.genfromtxt("stack_063.csv", dtype=data_types, delimiter=',',
                        converters={
                            7: lambda x: x.replace('"', ''),
                            8: lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '"%H%M"').time()
                        })
print(data)
```

This gives:

```
[(1, 10721, 12478, 5, 0, 0, 0, 'A1', datetime.time(5, 55))
 (1, 10722, 12479, 1, 0, 0, 0, 'A2', datetime.time(15, 55))]
```

Yet, I don't really know whether this is a good idea or not...

Answer (score 0):

I would also consider using Pandas module:

```
In [137]: import pandas as pd

In [138]: file_name = r'D:\temp\dt.csv'

In [139]: df = pd.read_csv(file_name, header=None, sep=',', skipinitialspace=True)

In [140]: df
Out[140]:
   0      1      2  3  4  5  6   7     8
0  1  10721  12478  5  0  0  0  A1   555
1  1  10722  12479  1  0  0  0  A2  1555

In [141]: df[8] = pd.to_datetime(df[8], format='%H%M').dt.time

In [142]: df
Out[142]:
   0      1      2  3  4  5  6   7         8
0  1  10721  12478  5  0  0  0  A1  05:55:00
1  1  10722  12479  1  0  0  0  A2  15:55:00
```